# WPF ListBox цвет выделенного при потере фокуса

Tags: wpf, listbox, background-color

есть 2 листбокса, в которых нужно выбрать пункты. при потере фокуса фоновый цвет выделенного пункта становится серым. как задать стиль чтобы поменять этот цвет?

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Selector.IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Background" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Selector.IsFocused" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: А как вы пробовали?

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавил стиль в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
</ListBox.Resources>
```